# GWT : Celltable Multiselection , MouseDown event?

Tags: gwt, event-handling, mouseover, celltable, multipleselection

I've got a CellTable, which has 4 columns:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
```

Goal:

User can select multiple columns while holding mouse button down and hovering over the columns.

e.g User clicks on column 1 and holds the mouse button down, moves over column 2 and 3 resulting in column 2 and 3 being selected.

I tried:

```
final MultiSelectionModel<data> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<BestellungData>();
    cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);

    cellTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<data>()
            {

                @Override
                public void onCellPreview(
                        CellPreviewEvent<data> event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if ("click".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {

                        selectionModel.setSelected(event.getValue(), true);

                    }
                }


    });
```

However it doesn't work.

Comment: `MultiSelectionModel` is used to select multiple rows, not multiple columns.

Comment: hm is it even possible to select mulitple columns

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
private boolean isFocus, isFocusMouseDown;
private int lastStyledRow = -1;
private Set<Integer> columns = new HashSet<Integer>();

...

table.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<Contact>() {

    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<Contact> event) {
        if ("focus".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            isFocus = true;
            if (lastStyledRow != -1) {
                NodeList<TableCellElement> cells = table.getRowElement(lastStyledRow)
                        .getCells();
                for (int col : columns) {
                    cells.getItem(col).removeClassName("selectedCell");
                }
                columns.clear();
            }
        }
        if ("blur".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            isFocus = false;
            isFocusMouseDown = false;
            lastStyledRow = event.getIndex();

            NodeList<TableCellElement> cells = table.getRowElement(event.getIndex())
                    .getCells();
            for (int col : columns) {
                cells.getItem(col).addClassName("selectedCell");
            }
        }

        if ("mousedown".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType()) && isFocus) {
            isFocusMouseDown = true;
        }

        if ("mouseover".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType()) && isFocusMouseDown) {
            columns.add(event.getColumn());
        }
    }

});
```

Here is the dummy CSS for selected cell

```
.selectedCell{
    border: 2px solid #F3F7FB;
    background-color: #F00;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

In the above code, we are listening for few events and based on their sequence we can identify the selected columns.

Sequence of events:

- Starting point is `focus` event on any column
- Then `mousedown` event to start dragging on anther columns
- If `focus` and `mousedown` both are true then collect all the columns on `mouseover` event
- Finally on `blur` event, change the style of all the selected cells.
- Reset the style of last selected cells on next `focus` event

snapshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tested this under Chromium 33.0.1750.152, but unfortunately, the `mousedown` event happens just before the `focus` event, so it doesn't work. It also doesn't work if I try it on the columns headers, because I receive only the `focus` and `blur` event, and nothing else (no `mousedown` or `mouseover`).

Comment: I have tested it on Firefox 26. Please can you verify it on Firefox? Meanwhile I am testing it on Chrome also.

Comment: Its working fine for Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 also. I have updated my post along with snapshots.